# I want to generate PDF automation report in XUnit using selenium driver and .net in visual studio?

Tags: automated-tests, reporting, xunit, functional-testing

I want that results of the assertions whether passed or failed (in both cases, expected results equal or not to actual result) are shown in PDF file. I am newbie to programming and automation testing. Please tell me what else details you need so that I can provide those details.I am using XUnit framework I don't have a hint how to proceed further. I have written test cases ad these test cases execute well but I have no idea how to generate report in PDF.